# Componentes em Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, componentes

Não consegui entender até onde posso dividir meus componentes no Vue.js

> É comum que um aplicativo seja organizado em uma árvore de componentes
>   aninhados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Por exemplo, você pode ter componentes para um cabeçalho, barra
>   lateral e área de conteúdo, cada um contendo normalmente outros
>   componentes para links de navegação, postagens de blog, etc.

É correto então eu fazer dessa maneira?

1. Menu

   2. Submenu

      3. Tópicos do submenu

Vamos imaginar essa seguinte imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

<strike>Então:</strike>

Menu seria o Avô, submenu o pai e os tópicos os filhos?

Não entendi ao certo como funciona corretamente essa parte de components.

Se eu tivesse então mais um submenu em Biology ele entraria aqui sendo como neto (do pai claro)?

Edit 1: Vou dar em versão de código, isso pode ajudar a esclarecer mais a pergunta:

#### JS

```
        Vue.component('navbar',{

            template: '#navbar'

        })
        Vue.component('submenu',{

            template: '#submenu'

        })

        Vue.component('lista-submenu',{

            template: '#lista-submenu' 

        })
```

Ok, aqui ficará mais claro, eu tenho 3 componentes `navbar`, `submenu`e `lista-submenu`

O `navbar` seria o Learn da foto

O `submenu` Home, Knowledge Map, Math, Science, etc

A `lista-submenu` Biology, Chemistry, Physics...

Agora o que acontece se eu tiver outro submenu?

#### Exemplo

Empresa -> `navbar`

Fale Conosco, Entre em contato, O que somos -> `submenu`

(Vazio) -> `lista-submenu`

**Dúvida:**

1. Vai ser ou outro componente, tipo `lista-submenu-2`
2. Até onde eu posso continuar quebrando em componentes

Comment: Menu pai é o menu principal exemplo:

Inicio Empresa Blog Contato << são menus pais

Os submenus que pertencem a eles são os filhos.

Uma forma simples de entender isso é o seguinte, tem o líder e seus subordinados o menu pai é o líder e os submenus seus subordinados.

Comment: E os tópicos seriam netos?

Comment: Não tem tópicos em menu, só submenus '-'

Comment: Olha sua print, é um menu hambúrguer e um menu com submenus.

Comment: Vou editar a pergunta, melhor.

Answer (score 0):

Vou te explicar oque é menu e oque é submenu.

```
<nav class="navbar">
<!--Container do menu -->
</nav>

<nav class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <!--Tudo que está nesse ul é menu -->
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Empresa
         <ul>
          <!-- Tudo que está nesse ul é submenu -->
            <li>Nossa história</li>
         </ul>
      </li>
    <ul>
</nav>
```

*Learn é o container do menu escondido conhecido como Hambúrguer, e após clicar em cima dele abre o menu com seus submenus.

Acho que assim fica mais claro